# Memoria Freese skill Material Killer

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

So I got one Lefiya (Incantation) who has an ability Material Killer: Ability pt. +50% toward Material. However I used her in both Rampage and regular stories with no apparent increase in either quantity or quality of drops. Any idea what this skill does?